# Visual Studio Team Services: Agents Configuration for different environments in release definition

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, ms-release-management, build-agent

I am using Visual Studio Team Services, Release management and Continuous integration on the cloud. My release definition contains two environments: Dev and PRO.

I want to know what the possible configuration if i don't want to buy a license.
we need to associate each of the environments with specific agent. I guess they are called private agents.

So are the agents installed on those release environments (which are on local domain) private agents? if yes, can i configure those 2 environments to run under same agents and how?

What is the possible configuration where  i can create 2 environments, each one corresponds to a different physical machine without paying for additional agents?

Comment: what is the down vote for? really confusing, i am asking because its not clear. If you have a problem to clarify ambiguities, then by pass the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to have a single Agent per network that you are deploying to (unless you want to deploy in parallel).

The Agent is an orchestrator  and does not need to be installed on the target environments. You use remote  PowerShell (or other scripting) to execute tasks on  the target servers for deployment.

Comment: Thanks @MrHinsh. Lets say  one of the environments (QA) has three physical zones ( Zone 1: Web, Zone 2: Application Services, Zone 3: data tier). In Zone 1, I have 3 web servers in one network (where different releases are deployed on each server) and in Zone 2 I have 3 servers. So, this means I have to install an agent per Zone, not per Server? Is this agent called a private agent according to Microsoft?