# How to set up RM agents in Visual Studio Team Services to deploy backend changes for mulitple environments

Tags: visual-studio, build, azure-devops, setup-deployment, continuous-deployment

I am confused while creating the agents. Do we need to create multiple agents for each environment or single agent will work.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the answer is No, You can use just one agent to deploy your build to several environments. But in some condition, for example, the environments are assigned for different networks, then you may need to setup one agent per network.

Similar question: [Visual Studio Team Services: Agents Configuration for different environments in release definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751201/visual-studio-team-services-agents-configuration-for-different-environments-in)

Comment: Is the back end RM setup is same as front end ?

Comment: @RajuRajoriya What do you mean by the "back end" and "front end"?